# SQL compare Workdays

Tags: sql

Currently I have 2 years worth of Sales data, and my company wants a weekday to weekday comparison between the 2 years

basically the Sales Numbers for Wednesday April 1st 2020 should be compared to Wednesday April 3rd 2019 (weekday to weekday comparison, instead of calendar year)

i'm trying to come up with some sort of case statement that will allow me to add a helper column so I can then put it into an excel Pivot table, or use a join, but I'm a bit stumped on how to go about it

Basically I thought if I could come up with some way to assign a sequence to each workday, it could be done

for example Monday #1 in April could get the code MApril1 Monday #2 in April could get MApril2 Monday #1 in June could get MJune1 and so forth (I could just do that for both years and that would make it very easy)

but I just cant think of a way to write that sequence or case, any suggestions?

long story short lets say I gave you the date Wednesday April 8th 2020, how would you identify this as the second Wednesday of April 2020?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: You may need to think over your "anchor" date more. Would you be wanting to consider this the second Wednesday of April 2020 or the 15th Wednesday of 2020? If you're using `<x> <day> of <month>` you'll run in to a lot of invalid dates because often a month 1 year will have a different number of say Thursdays than the next year.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood clearly but I will try to help. 
Don't hesitate to tell me if I'm wrong.
I assumed you used SQL Server. Please add the SQL you use into the tags.

I would count the week number.

```
set datefirst 1; -- depending on the language
declare @weekNb int;
select @weekNb = datepart(week, @yourInitialDate); -- getting the number of the week
declare @dayNb = int; 
select @dayNb = datepart(weekday, @yourInitialDate); -- getting the number of the day
```

And now, using the function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21951046/8233385) I would get the day from the current year :

```
select dbo.date_from_week_number_day(YEAR(GetDate(),weekNb,dayNb);
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but as it turns out I was overthinking it all i had to do was subtract 364 and I get the prior workday

Comment: OK I misunderstood then. I thought if it was a monday you wanted to fall on a monday at the same moment of the year.
Dont forget to remove 365 when leap year

Comment: Crazy thing is I actually don't have to do that Wednesday April 1st 2020 
Syncs up to Wednesday April 3rd 2019, (2 Day variance)

Friday January 10th 2020 Syns up to Friday January 11th 2019(1 Day Variance) in both cases just subtracting 364 works (I think its because even in a leap year its not like the week stops being Monday - Sunday)

Comment: I thought this wasn't only for one year but something which would work no matter the year. My bad.